# Running a program in XP freaks out display settings

Tags: windows-xp, display

I've got an XP box that is running a custom, old school program (explains the XP, don't hate). This program has always worked fine.

From last week, every time the .exe is double clicked, the graphics started going to 8 bit and sometimes messing up the screen resolution (Literally every time)

This program runs on 180 identical XP boxes around the world and has never done this before, so it isn't the program.

I tried re-installing the computer's graphics drivers, but that didn't help. I replaced the .exe with a fresh copy, that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the shortcut to the application and take a look at the compatibility tab.

It sounds to me like someone may have enabled reduced colour mode and possibly a few of the other visual compatibility settings

[image]

Comment: You're a genius - worked like a charm.  Thanks.